# How to match two columns with same model?

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I have these two tables below and I want to build a relationship between from - code and where - code so I can access country name with `$proc->from->name`

I've tried this but it doesn't work

```
public function from()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Country', 'from', 'code');
}

public function where()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Country', 'where', 'code');
}
```

procs:

```
id  | user_id   | from | where
--------------------------------
1   |    1      | GB   | US
2   |    2      | AZ   | TR
```

countries

```
id  | name         | code |
------------------------
1   |United States | US   |
2   |   France     | FR   |
```

Comment: You have your params the wrong way round e.g. `'App\Country', 'code', 'from'`. I would suggest changing your field names so that they don't match your relationship names as it will more than likely lead to issues down the line e.g. `from_code` and `where_code`. I definitely suggest changing your `where()` relationship name to something else so that it doesn't conflict with `where()` on the query builder .Lastly, it might be more of an idea to use the country `id` rather than the code but it definitely isn't essential (`from_id`, and `where_id`).

Comment: @Rwd I didn't quite understand. Is problem in the relationship name ot it's just suggestion. Cause it didn't work after modifying the names with _code suffix

Comment: The initial issue is order of your `hasOne` params i.e. your `from` relationship should be `$this->hasOne('App\Country', 'code', 'from')`. The second (and arguably most important) issue is the use of `from` and `where` as these are both methods on the Query Builder. Lastly, having your relationship names match your field names will more than likely cause an issue as well e.g. should `$proc->from` give you the field value or the related model?

Comment: It should give the field value and it gives. I modified everything according to your suggestions but still doesn't work

Comment: @Rwd OK I got it working finally. I just forgot that I should restart tinker everytime after modifying the code. Thanks you very much for your time :)

Comment: Glad I could help!